# Rounding down a floating point number to an integer value without a floor function in C

Tags: c, function, rounding, floor

I need to write a function in C that rounds down a floating point number to an integer. For example, 10.6 becomes 10. 22.1249 becomes 22. However, I can't use a floor function. Can this be done?

Comment: Just cast it to integer (or another appropriate integral number type)?

Comment: You need to be more precise with your description. Does 'down' mean 'towards zero' or 'towards negative infinity'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Floor

Use integer cast to round down float number.

```
float yourFloat = 10.5;
int down = (int)yourfloat; //down = 10.
```

---

## Nearest integer

To round to the nearest integer, add `0.5f` to your float, then cast.

```
float f1 = 10.3, f2 = 10.8;
int i1, i2;
i1 = (int)(f1 + 0.5f); //i1 = 10
i2 = (int)(f2 + 0.5f); //i2 = 11
```

## Ceil

To round number up, use if statement with some casts:

```
int result = (int)yourFloat;
if (yourFloat - (int)yourFloat > 0) {
    result++;
}
```

Comment: Or, alternatvely for Ceil, first add 1.0 to the float, then cast (ok, will add one if it already is integral... so add 1 - epsilon ;))

Comment: Well, here is `if` which will do the epsilon job.

Comment: As I said, add (1.0f - FLT_EPSILON)

Comment: Your floor is a truncate which rounds up negative values. Your nearest integer gives -9 and -10 for -10.3 and -10.8.